# Change port in Kali Responder

Tags: http, webdav

By default when starting `Responder` in `Kali linux` it starts `http` server as well as `SMB` server.
I can disable `HTTP` server in `Responder.conf` file from starting at all.
How to tell `Responder` to listen on `SMB` server for port 80 ?

EDITED:

I'm testing with \\192.168.1.119:80

here is a capture when HTTP on responder is disabled:
[image]

here is a capture when HTTP on responder is enabled:
[image]

here is a capture when HTTP on responder is disabled and I enabled socat on linux:

socat TCP-LISTEN:80,fork TCP:192.168.1.119:445
[image]

Any other ideas?

Comment: Why would you want to change the port SMB uses? The attack will not be successful if you do. However, it may be possible to change it. You could edit the code, since it's open source, you could add a redirection rule with `iptables`, or you could use a tool like `socat` to proxy connections from 80 to 445. That said, it's not going to work the way you want it to.

Comment: Because port 445 is blocked, I want everything to test via port 80.
So if I proxy to port 445 the Kali would think it's working with 445 and client still believes it's on port 80 but with SMB protocol in that situation?

Comment: Maybe, but the client is not going to talk to SMB on port 80. Windows will not use anything other than 139 or 445.

Comment: What if i will test file:// or its:// URI schemes?

Comment: Hmmm in that case I do not know.

Comment: Actually if I force \\server:80 on client I believe it will default to WebDAV protocol.
But i'm not sure if Responder will understand it